# Cannot read property '0' of undefined javascript

Tags: javascript, silverlight, xaml, visibility, onload

I'm having a extremely annoying error with a JavaScript project.

I am working on a project where I to be able to show and collapse Ellipses from a roster.
There are 3 values for each X axis, but with the buttons Total, Nouns and Verbs I need to be able to show only the Total values, noun values and verb values.

This is how my Ellipse is programmed in the xaml file

```
<Ellipse xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
         x:Name="total1" 
         Fill="Red"
         Stroke="DarkRed"
         Width="15"
         Height="15"
         Visibility="Collapsed"
         Canvas.Top="228.4447"
         Canvas.Left="132.5"/>
```

There are 14 of each, 14 totals, 14 nouns and 14 verbs. 
Now the code behind my textblock/border to call the JavaScript function is

```
<Border xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        x:Name="totalButton"
        Canvas.Top="20"
        Canvas.Left="90"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="0"
        BorderBrush="#EEE8AA"
        BorderThickness="1.5"
        Background="DarkSlateGray"
        Width="80"
        Height="20"
        MouseLeftButtonUp="showTotals"
        Cursor="Hand">
    <TextBlock Foreground="Ivory" FontWeight="ExtraBlack" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Center">Total</TextBlock>       
</Border>
```

And this is how I try to load them into an Array in the Onloaded function.

```js
function onLoaded() {
    defaultPage = document.getElementById('NounVerb');
    totalValues = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i <= 14; i++) {
        totalValues[i] = defaultPage.content.findName('total' + (i + 1));
    }
}
```

I also declared the `var totalValues;` as a global in the document.

But when I press the Total button, which calls the ShowTotals function, that looks like this

```js
function showTotals() {  
    for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        totalValues[i].Visibility = 'Visible';
    }
}
```

I'm getting nothing, I'm really stuck at this, it's probably something pretty obvious but I'm getting tunnelvision I guess. Hopefully someone sees the problem.

Comment: is this line correct: totalValues[i] = defaultPage.content.findName('total' + (i + 1)); " Should it say 'totalValues' instead of 'total' ?

Comment: I'm searching for content with the name total + a number from 1 till 14 to load in my array. I don't think the mistake is in that line.

Comment: Is onloaded actually called, does `defaultPage.content.findName('total' + (i + 1));` actually return a value? `console.log()` is your friend here.

Comment: What environment is this running in? Silverlight?

Comment: @epascarello, normally the OnLoaded function is running fine, i tested it with an allert at OnLoaded. This is shown as is should.

Comment: @ChrisTavares, yes it is running in Silverlight

Comment: And `console.log(defaultPage.content.findName('total' + (i + 1)));`?

Comment: @epascarello, when I add your line to the OnLoaded function, but change the (i + 1) to just 1, and evaluate it in the javascript console, i get 'cannot read property 'content' of null'

Comment: that would say that `defaultPage` is null

Comment: @epascarello, that would be strange, in my html file, i call '<script src="Javascript/NounVerb.js" type="text/javascript"></script>' and geve my object the id="NounVerb", that id I use to call the page in the OnLoaded function.
This is my object in the html page
        <object 
            id="NounVerb"
            width="100%"
            height="100%"  
            type="application/x-silverlight">       
         <param name="source" value="Xaml/NounVerb.xaml"/>          
        </object>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and it is pretty simple.
Because I generated the xaml file from a xsl file, i never thought to look for the error there. But the  `Loaded="onLoad"` function was not included in at the top of the Grid, so like epascarello said, the onLoad function was never loaded.

Thank you for the quick help.

Regards